# Offline restores of a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, docker, dump

I want to provide initial data in a Docker container inheriting from the official PostgreSQL image.

*Is there a way I can restore a PostgreSQL dump from the command-line (using `pg_restore`) while the database server is not running?*

I [found](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/91) that the following works, but doesn't use `pg_restore` :

```
gosu postgres postgres --single -jE <<-EOSQL
   CREATE LANGUAGE plpythonu;
EOSQL
```

I've read about the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` in the [official page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), but it only accepts raw SQL, and I'd like to keep modifications to the official image to a minimum.

Comment: No, that's no possible. `pg_restore` requires a running Postgres server

Comment: That's what I feared, but I figured I'd ask anyway. The official Postgres Docker image uses pg_ctl to start the server, waits for it to become online, restores data and shuts it down. The best I could find for now is the line I posted in my question (which does start a server)...

Comment: Why is it a problem to start the server for you?

Comment: It seemed a little too much to start the server for restoring a dump when building the image, but i ended up doing that anyway